# Checking that a series of dates are within a series of different intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, intervals, lubridate

This seems like it would be a simple thing to do, but I am stumped.

I was using tidyverse material as a guide:  [here](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html)

I have a list of recession time periods, and I want to create a data frame as an output that lists every date and whether or not that date is in a recession.  I would like to keep the solution in dplyr format.

**Here is a reproducible example**

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data set

my_df <-
structure(list(recession_start = structure(c(1400, 3652, 4199, 
7486, 11382, 13848), class = "Date"), recession_end = structure(c(1885, 
3834, 4687, 7729, 11627, 14396), class = "Date"), recession_interval = new("Interval", 
    .Data = c(41904000, 15724800, 42163200, 20995200, 21168000, 
    47347200), start = structure(c(120960000, 315532800, 362793600, 
    646790400, 983404800, 1196467200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


    > my_df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  recession_start recession_end recession_interval            
  <date>          <date>        <Interval>                    
1 1973-11-01      1975-03-01    1973-11-01 UTC--1975-03-01 UTC
2 1980-01-01      1980-07-01    1980-01-01 UTC--1980-07-01 UTC
3 1981-07-01      1982-11-01    1981-07-01 UTC--1982-11-01 UTC
4 1990-07-01      1991-03-01    1990-07-01 UTC--1991-03-01 UTC
5 2001-03-01      2001-11-01    2001-03-01 UTC--2001-11-01 UTC
6 2007-12-01      2009-06-01    2007-12-01 UTC--2009-06-01 UTC



# Get every day in the range of dates
my_dates <- seq(first(my_df$recession_start), today(), by = "day")


# Create a list of intervals
recession_intervals <- list(my_df$recession_interval)


# Check to see if `my_dates` are in the intervals
recession <- my_dates %within% recession_intervals  # Throws warning and does not give expected results
```

I suspect this is because my list of dates is a single list vs. multiple lists as in the tidyverse example, but I'm not sure how to create multiple lists other than manually.

The desired output would be a data frame with each date and a "TRUE" or "FALSE" column indicating if that daily date is in a recession interval.  Something like:

```
recession_df <- data.frame(Date = my_dates, recession = recession)
```

Output would look like this:

```
         Date recession
1  1973-11-01      TRUE
2  1973-11-02      TRUE
3  1973-11-03      TRUE
4  1973-11-04      TRUE
5  1973-11-05      TRUE
6  1973-11-06      TRUE
7  1973-11-07      TRUE
8  1973-11-08      TRUE
9  1973-11-09      TRUE
10 1973-11-10      TRUE
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to loop over (`map`) the 'my_dates', check if there are `any` dates that are `%within%` the 'recession_interval column, create a `tibble` with each 'date' and the logical output and convert to a single dataset with `_dfr` (row binding)

```
library(purrr)
out <- map_dfr(my_dates, ~ tibble(Date = .x, 
     recession = any(Date %within% my_df$recession_interval)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17,381 x 2
   Date       recession
   <date>     <lgl>    
 1 1973-11-01 TRUE     
 2 1973-11-02 TRUE     
 3 1973-11-03 TRUE     
 4 1973-11-04 TRUE     
 5 1973-11-05 TRUE     
 6 1973-11-06 TRUE     
 7 1973-11-07 TRUE     
 8 1973-11-08 TRUE     
 9 1973-11-09 TRUE     
10 1973-11-10 TRUE     
# … with 17,371 more rows
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.  I was looking for output that would be something like the following:  Date column would have every date listed.  recession column would have a single "TRUE" or "FALSE" for each date.

Comment: @DaveM how many rows you are expecting.  Is it `length(my_dates)#
[1] 17381`

Comment: A row for each date in my_dates.  Yes, 17,381

Comment: @DaveM let's say if you are using the first my-date i.e. `my_df %>% mutate(new = my_dates[1] %within% recession_interval)`, there will be 5 elements.  Are you expecting 17381 * 5

Comment: Output would look like this          Date recession
1  1973-11-01      TRUE
2  1973-11-02      TRUE
3  1973-11-03      TRUE
4  1973-11-04      TRUE
5  1973-11-05      TRUE
6  1973-11-06      TRUE
7  1973-11-07      TRUE
8  1973-11-08      TRUE
9  1973-11-09      TRUE
10 1973-11-10      TRUE

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear (showed expected output)

Comment: @DaveM The issue is that each element of my_dates when checked with each element of recession_interval will have 17381 * 5

Comment: Understood.  I am trying to just check if a given date is in a recession period.  Not sure how to do that with the interval construct.  Maybe take `max`, so that if it is in a recession interval it would return the equivalent of `TRUE`

Comment: Yes, that's it!  `recession <- unlist(lapply(my_dates, function(x) any(x %within% my_df$recession_interval)))`

`recession_df <- data.frame(Date = my_dates, recession = recession)`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
in_recession <- 
  tibble(date = my_dates) %>% 
  mutate(
    recession = date %>% 
      map_lgl(~any(.x %within% my_df$recession_interval))
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the following solution, without using the `recession_interval` column:

```
library(purrr)

my_dates %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fall = any(map2_lgl(my_df$recession_start, my_df$recession_end, 
                             ~ between(value, .x, .y))))

# A tibble: 17,382 x 2
# Rowwise: 
   value      fall 
   <date>     <lgl>
 1 1973-11-01 TRUE 
 2 1973-11-02 TRUE 
 3 1973-11-03 TRUE 
 4 1973-11-04 TRUE 
 5 1973-11-05 TRUE 
 6 1973-11-06 TRUE 
 7 1973-11-07 TRUE 
 8 1973-11-08 TRUE 
 9 1973-11-09 TRUE 
10 1973-11-10 TRUE 
# ... with 17,372 more rows
```